# Regex to match a string that may contain Chinese characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression which could match a string that possibly includes Chinese characters. Examples:

```
hahdj5454_fd.fgg"
example.com/list.php?keyword=关键字
example.com/list.php?keyword=php
```

I am using this expression:

```
$matchStr =  '/^[a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\/[^x7f-xff]+$/i';
$str      =  "http://example.com/list.php?keyword=关键字";

if ( ! preg_match($matchStr, $str)){
    exit('WRONG');
}else{
    echo "RIGHT"; 
}
```

It matches plain English strings like that `dasdsdsfds` or `http://example.com/list.php`, but it doesn't match strings containing Chinese characters. How can I resolve this?

Comment: It isn't really clear what you exactly want to match ...

Comment: Also, there is a syntax problem in your regex. You seem to have tried to nest character classes (which isn't possible), but the number of brackets is imbalanced anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to extend the set of letters that this regex matches from ASCII to all Unicode letters, then you can use

```
$matchStr =  '#^[\pL 0-9~%.:_/-]+$#u';
```

I've removed the `[^x7f-xff` part which didn't make any sense (in your regex, it would have matched an opening bracket, a caret, and some ASCII characters that were already covered by the `a-z` and `0-9` parts of that character class).

Comment: I have a question,how is the difference between '#' and '/' in regular? i try to find that in google,but,there is no find information.could you tell me about that?Thanks

Comment: @mike: No fundamental difference - you can use any non-alnum ASCII character as a regex delimiter (even paired ones like `<...>`, although that's not used often for good reasons). `/` is the de facto standard, but if your regex contains slashes, using other delimiters is often preferable because then you don't have to escape them. `#`, `~`, `&` and `%` are used often because they have no special meaning in regexes.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$str = "http://mysite/list.php?keyword=关键字";

if (preg_match('/[\p{Han}]/simu', $str)) {
    echo "Contains Chinese Characters"; 
}else{
    exit('WRONG'); // Doesn't contains Chinese Characters
}
```