# php mysql and multiple language verification

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a php game and I am in the process of adding more languages such as **Russian** and **Chinese**.

For the most part this has been easy with multiple language files however I have hit just one problem.

In the Game they are able to enter a name at the start and I have the following code to validate the name:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $inputname);
```

My question is while this will work for english how would i do this for other languages, I only want them to input `a-zA-z0-9` in their language as well as make the name safe for input into a MySQL database.

Comment: "*make the name safe for input into a mysql database*" You are handling that wrong. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to match a string that may contain Chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382580/regex-to-match-a-string-that-may-contain-chinese-characters)

Comment: will $matchStr =  '#^[\pL 0-9~%.:_/-]+$#u'; 
match russian as well?